# If $0$ is the unique eigenvalue of a matrix $B:\mathbb{C}^k \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^k$, then B is nilpotent

Tags: linear-algebra

> **Proposition:** If $B:\mathbb{C}^k \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^k$ has only 0 as an eigenvalue, then $B$ is nilpotent.

I'm trying to grasp the proof of this result that is in the first volume of Taylor's differential equations series. It goes like this:

> The images of the powers of $B$ [$W_j := B^j(\mathbb{C}^k)$] form a
> decreasing sequence of finite-dimensional vector spaces, each
> invariant under $B$. This sequence must stabilize for some m, namely,
> $B: W_m \rightarrow W_m$ is bijective. If $W_m \neq 0$, $B$ has a
> nonzero eigenvalue.

I'm stuck on the last implication, why does $W_m \neq 0$ imply that $B$ has a
nonzero eigenvalue?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linear map $B \colon W_m \to W_m$ must have an eigenvalue (except in the special case that $W_m$ is zero-dimensional).

That eigenvalue cannot be $0$, because if $B(x) = 0$ for some nonzero $x \in W_m$, then $B\colon W_m \to W_m$ isn't the bijection we were promised. (Specifically, $x \ne 0$ but $B(x) = B(0)$.)